# Material UI First MenuItem not showing Tooltip if created using React.forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tooltip, menuitem

I have a common custom component (a `<MenuItem />` from Material-UI) that is wrapped in `React.forwardRef`. I use this in many places for displaying items in `<Menu />` components - sometimes a ref is passed, in other cases not.

I want this component to have a `<Tooltip />` but I find that the Tooltip does not display on the first instance of the common component in a Menu (but does show on other instances).

If i remove the prop `innerRef={ref}` from the `<MenuItem />` in my component, that does fix it - but I don't quite understand why?

I think I could resolve this by wrapping the `<MenuItem />` in e.g a `<span />`, but I'm keen to understand what is going on here and why the Tooltip is not showing?

https://codesandbox.io/s/new-fire-fngcof?file=/src/App.tsx

[image: Tooltip shown on second MenuItem]

[image: No Tooltip shown on first MenuItem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no property named `innerRef` in MUI or React.
Change that to `ref` and everything will work as expected.

```
<Tooltip title={props.tooltipTitle}>
  <MenuItem ref={ref}>Menu item</MenuItem>
</Tooltip>
```

If you are eager to know what is `innerRef`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211627/what-is-innerref-in-reactjs).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the info, that's super helpful - I had a closer read up and understand better now. There once was an `innerRef` prop in MUI I believe, which is why I was confused as to it not working - it looks like it will be deprecated in v5 and we should use `ref` going forward (https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-style-changes/#%E2%9C%85-replace-innerref-with-ref)

Comment: I suspected that `innerRef` might be used in older versions of MUI,  but now that you mentioned it, I became sure. Thanks.